# Cluster datapoints using kmeans sklearn in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, k-means

I am using the following python code to cluster my datapoints using kmeans.

```
data =  np.array([[30, 17, 10, 32, 32], [18, 20, 6, 20, 15], [10, 8, 10, 20, 21], [3, 16, 20, 10, 17], [3, 15, 21, 17, 20]])
kmeans_clustering = KMeans( n_clusters = 3 )
idx = kmeans_clustering.fit_predict( data )

#use t-sne
X = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform( data )

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()

#plot graph
colors = np.array([x for x in 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk'])
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=colors[kmeans_clustering.labels_])
plt.title('K-Means (t-SNE)')
plt.show()
```

However, the plot of the clusters I get is wrong as I get everything in one point.
[image: cluster plot]

Hence, please let me know where I am making my code wrong? I want to view the kmeans clusters seperately in my scatter plot.

**EDIT**

The t-sne vales I get are as follows.

```
[[  1.12758575e-04   9.30458337e-05]
 [ -1.82559784e-04  -1.06657936e-04]
 [ -9.56485652e-05  -2.38951623e-04]
 [  5.56515580e-05  -4.42453191e-07]
 [ -1.42039677e-04  -5.62548119e-05]]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the values for `X` after the t-SNE transform?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With the example data given, I get 5 points, with x- and y-values between (roughly) -200 and 200. What sklearn and numpy versions are you using?

Comment: @Evert Thank you very much for your comments. My numpy version is  1.13.0 and sklearn version is 0.18.1. Also, I have updated my tsne values in the question. Can you please let me know where I am making the code wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce using numpy 1.13.3 and sklearn 0.19

Comment: There are quite a few bug fixes in version 0.19 for `manifold.TSNE`. Try and upgrade your `sklearn` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `perplexity` parameter of the `TSNE`. The default value of the `perplexity` is 30, it seems that's too much for your case, even though the documentation states that `TSNE` is quite insensitive to this parameter.

> The perplexity is related to the number of nearest neighbors that is used in other manifold learning algorithms. Larger datasets usually require a larger perplexity. Consider selecting a value between 5 and 50. The choice is not extremely critical since t-SNE is quite insensitive to this parameter.

```
X = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=2.0).fit_transform( data )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot. do you see any other flaws in my code? :)

Comment: I don't, the other parts are ok.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use PCA (Principal Components Analysis) instead of t-SNE to plot your clusters:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
from sklearn.cluster import Kmeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data =  np.array([[30, 17, 10, 32, 32], [18, 20, 6, 20, 15], [10, 8, 10, 20, 
21], [3, 16, 20, 10, 17], [3, 15, 21, 17, 20]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
labels = kmeans.fit_predict(data)    

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
data_reduced = pca.fit_transform(data)
data_reduced = pd.DataFrame(data_reduced)

ax = data_reduced.plot(kind='scatter', x=0, y=1, c=labels, cmap='rainbow')
ax.set_xlabel('PC1')
ax.set_ylabel('PC2')
ax.set_title('Projection of the clustering on a the axis of the PCA')

for x, y, label in zip(data_reduced[0], data_reduced[1], kmeans.labels_):
    ax.annotate('Cluster {0}'.format(label), (x,y))
```

[image]